# How to set "query_cache_size" in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I it possible to configure Googles Cloud SQL? 
I need to set my query_cache_size but i don´t now how to access the Settings.

Answer (score 0):

you will not be able to set this variable as it is part of the restrictions for using Google Cloud SQL [1], You will need to contact with Google Cloud Support, for this enter your project in the Developer Console [2], then you will see a "Support" item link on the left menu.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/introduction
[2] https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: Hi Eric! really?! They charge lot of money for the google cloud services, minimize the option i´m able to configure and then they want me to pay for support?! - or is there a way to contact the support without a payed support ticket for these kind of request?

Comment: Hello, yes you can open a ticket as i mentioned above, they will reply as a reasonable effort even if you do not have a payed support.

Comment: hmm well, if it´s like you sad, they have hide it pretty smart ;) - i even can´t go to any support area without a support membership. they just offering community and billing support for bronze members..